# PayPal Sandbox can't complete purchase

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

This question may have been asked in a few different forms, but I can't find anything that works.

I was testing out some of my PayPal hooks on my website, and it let me pay the first few times, but then it stopped. I created a new buyer account and a new merchant account but they didn t work either. I also cleared my cookies for PayPal, but still nothing worked.

This is what it says when attempting to send payment.
[image: This is what it says when attempting to send payment.]

Is there some sort of limit or "fraud" detection on the sandbox?

I am really confused and have been fighting this for most of the day. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Add the code to connect with paypal sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Rafiq. I have my cart sent to PayPal Sanbox and it was working, but then it stopped. It appears to have started working again this morning though.